# For every positive integer n, show that there is a ring with exactly n ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Please may I have a hint for this question? I am trying this by induction at the moment, with the base case being {0}. I have assumed the result holds for integers up to and including n-1. My thought process for showing the "n" case is to have I be a ring with n-1 ideals, and show that I can be maximal in a larger ring R so that R is the nth ideal in R but I can't think of any examples or proofs at this point.

Comment: Note that the ring $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ has exactly $2$ ideals, not $1$. Indeed, there is the $(0)$ ideal, but also the whole ring itself is an ideal generated by the element $1$, i.e. $\langle 1 \rangle = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is the other ideal.

Comment: Ah yes you're right thank you, that was quite stupid of me, given every field has exactly 2 ideals. I should use the zero ring.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint 1:** How many ideals does $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ have? The answer will depend on the divisors of $m$.

**Hint 2.** What happens when you choose $m=2^{n-1}$ for $n\geq 2$ in Hint 1?